# search array for part of a string

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to search my array to see if the value for `target` match.

```js
(function ($) {
    
    $.fn.validate = function (x) {

        return this.each(function () {

            var wrapper = $(this);

            var xx = $.extend({
                obj: "",
            }, x || {});

            function initialized() {

                $(wrapper).children().bind('keyup', function (e) {
                    
                    console.log($.grep(xx.obj, function (t) { return t.target.indexOf($(e.target).attr("name")) }));

                });

            }
            initialized();
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
$('form').validate({ obj: [{ "target": "name=Username", "required": true, "xmin": "5", "xmax": "16" }, { "target": "name=Email", "required": true, "xmin": "5", "xmax": "16" }] });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
                    <input name="Username" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input type="button" value="Save" />
                </form>
```

This line: `$.grep(xx.obj, function (t) { return t.target == $(e.target).attr("name") }).length` returns if it finds a match. I know it says `==` so it would only return a match if it match exatly.

Is it posible to make it do something like this: `$.grep(xx.obj, function (t) { return t.target.contains($(e.target).attr("name")) }).length`

**Edit**
Changed code to match Z-Bone Answer. still don't work correctly

When a user type in an input field, it will take the `Name` value `($(e.target).attr("name"))` from that input and search the `xx.obj` to see if the value match the any of the `obj.target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution now.

```
$.grep(xx.obj, function (t) {
    return t.target.split('=')[1] == $(e.target).attr(t.target.split('=')[0])
})[0]
```

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.validate = function (x) {

        return this.each(function () {

            var wrapper = $(this);

            var xx = $.extend({
                obj: "",
            }, x || {});

            function initialized() {

                $(wrapper).bind('keyup', function (e) {

                    console.log($.grep(xx.obj, function (t) {
                        return t.target.split('=')[1] == $(e.target).attr(t.target.split('=')[0])
                    })[0]);


                });

            }
            initialized();
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
$('form').validate({ obj: [{ "target": "name=Username", "required": true, "xmin": "5", "xmax": "16" }, { "target": "name=Email", "required": true, "xmin": "5", "xmax": "16" }] });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
                    <input name="Username" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input type="button" value="Save" />
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to see if a string contains a value.
If I understand your need correctly, you want to see if the entire input value is contained in any of the *target* keys in your JSON object.
To do this you shouldn't test each key event - since that will be testing a single character each keyup event.
You want to to get the full input value each time a keyup event occurs and test if it exists in any of the *target* keys in your array.

In the following code I changed your code just slightly so you see where I'm going with this. I test to see only if the *username* input value is contained in the JSON. You can also add the email input value to be tested. 

 
 
Please note I changed both HTML and JS

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.validate = function(x) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var wrapper = $(this);
            var xx = $.extend({
                obj: "",
            }, x || {});

            function initialized() {
                $(wrapper).children().bind('keyup', function(e) {
                    var userNameValue = $('#username').val();
                    console.log($.grep(xx.obj, function(t) {
                        return (t.target.indexOf(userNameValue) > -1);
                    }).length);
                });
            }
            initialized();
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
$('form').validate({
    obj: [{
        "target": "name=Username",
        "required": true,
        "xmin": "5",
        "xmax": "16"
    }, {
        "target": "name=Email",
        "required": true,
        "xmin": "5",
        "xmax": "16"
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <input id="username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" />
  <input name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I changed my code to use `indexOf` but it dont work 100% correctly. when it search for the attr it returns both objects in my array. (run code and you will see).

Comment: Please elaborate about what final result you want to get. I tried to explain about achieving string contains feature...